# How can i fetch drop down list values and insert onto an Excel file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am trying to fetch drop down list values and insert onto an excel file.

I have written a code, but it is showing an error on the page.

Error shown as "java.lang.NullPointerException".

Below is the code written :-

```
    package test.neha;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Dropdown_extraction {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    WebDriverWait wait;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    XSSFCell cell;
    @Test
    public void list_items() throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("file:///C:/Users/neha.sharma/Desktop/File.html");
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        File src=new File("D:\\Drop_values.xlsx");
        WebElement Element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/fieldset/p/select"));
        Element.click();

        FileInputStream fr=new FileInputStream(src);
        workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(fr);
        XSSFSheet sh = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        List<WebElement> L= (List) driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form/fieldset/p/select"));

        for(WebElement e:L)
        {       

                    String value=e.getText();
                    System.out.println("Print the values as below:"+value);
                    System.out.println("Values are:"+ e.getText());

                    Row row=sh.getRow(0);
                    Cell[] cell=new Cell[10];
                    if(row==null)
                    {
                        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
                        {
                            cell[i]=row.createCell(i);
                        }
                        if(cell[1]==null)
                        {
                            cell[1].setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                            cell[1].setCellValue(value);
                        }

                        if(cell[2]==null)
                        {
                            cell[2].setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                            cell[2].setCellValue(value);
                        }
                    }

                    /*sh.getRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue(value);
                    sh.getRow(2).createCell(1).setCellValue(value);
                    sh.getRow(3).createCell(2).setCellValue(value);
                    sh.getRow(4).createCell(3).setCellValue(value);
                */
                    FileOutputStream Output = new FileOutputStream(src);
                    workbook.write(Output);
                    Output.close();







        }

        /*Select element_list=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/fieldset/p/select")));
        element_list.selectByVisibleText("Apple");*/
    }

}
```

Could anyone let me know the solution of this error. The error shown mostly in "Create Cell code" . 
Please help me out.

Comment: Error "No Pointer exception" is shown on Line of code as 
 : "cell[1].setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); "

Comment: Make sure the cell exists before writing to it?

Comment: how to check the same . can you suggest me little bit @Gagravarr

Comment: Either do a null check, or [do something like in the example code](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) and pass in a missing cell policy when you fetch